# Apply Holo theme to pre 3.0 Android versions?

Tags: android, android-layout, themes, android-theme, holoeverywhere

I am curious about how to apply HOLO theme in older android version devices. I know there is way using ActionBarSherlock library. But I am not very sure about how to accomplish it.
Any suggestion are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)

And [this](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere).

I hope this would help you. If you have any other questions, ask.

OK! So basically there is nothing wrong with what you're doing. AppCompact library should use old themes on old devices.

if you want to use Holo themes on old devices you should use HoloEverywhere.

Comment: Can u please tell how to use HoloEverywhere library?

Comment: Well, have you tried to read the manual?

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#android-studio--intellij-idea

Comment: Thanks.. i tried http://www.begincodingnow.com/tutorial/adding-action-bar-support-library-to-apps-running-on-android-2-1/ and its working fine.. but when I put button into my XML it still shows as Android 2.2 color and theme for button.. what to do for changing the theme of button as in HOLO?

Comment: Well, you should probably show us some code, but for now I think that problem is with styles. Are you sure that you applied correct styles in manifest?

Our last change will now be done within the AndroidManifest.xml file.  Under the Application tab, we are going to change the Theme.  We will now change the theme from @style/AppTheme to the new @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar or any of the variants below.

Comment: Yes.. i done that change in AndroidManifest file.. thats why I can see ActionBar in 2.2 version.. but button theme is not getting updated.. and regarding code I haven't implemented any code, just put the button in XML file.

Comment: How to use theme for XML files?

Comment: well, I mean in Eclipse there is a spinner in "graphical layout" in which you could choose theme to show in preview.
But where do you actually see this button in wrong theme? In your device or the in preview in Eclipse?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42954/discussion-between-user1685095-and-virag)

Answer (score 1):

Use app compact library from Android support library

http://www.begincodingnow.com/tutorial/adding-action-bar-support-library-to-apps-running-on-android-2-1/

Comment: Thanks.. i tried it.. and working fine.. but when I put button into my XML it still shows as Android 2.2 color and theme for button.. wht to do?